# MYSQL Why While loop returns first record two times?

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop

I have two records in my DB and i want print them out.
So i wroted this:

```
<?php
$resDB = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("xe", $resDB);


 $aco = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM      pfields_content WHERE TRIM(field_12) IS NOT NULL)  ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($aco))
{

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT member_id FROM pfields_content WHERE TRIM(field_12) IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1");
$memberID = mysql_fetch_row($query1);

echo $memberID[0];
echo '<br>';




}
?>
```

And instead of two records (member ids):

1
2

It prints first record (member id) two times:

1
1

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You're running the exact same query twice and printing the same value. (You never do anything at all with the result from the outer query except use its number of results as the number of times to loop and run the inner query).

Comment: And DB queries inside of loops are usually a really bad idea performance-wise. Familiarize yourself with JOINs and see how you can get all the data you need with just one query. (How exactly, depends on your data model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two query are not correlated among them so you will have two result because your first query find two matches row, so it loop twice, while from second query you will always get the same values since it is executed once per loop. I would suggest to remove second query and print directly result from first query so you will print two differetns `id`

```
$aco = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM      pfields_content WHERE TRIM(field_12) IS NOT NULL)  ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($aco))
{
    echo $row['member_id']; // or whatever your column name is
}
```

Otherwise you can use selected member id from first query and use in second query with a `WHERE` clause limiting results to only `member_id = '$row['member_id']`.

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @user2405957 you welcome man! Don't forget to accept answer and upvote it to help people in the future with similar problems